# Update multiple field and rows in mysql database in input at once in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i am trying to achieve something where i can input multiple value into multiple field and update all field and row in the database with just one click..

the image below describe what i want to achieve more and image include the mysql database structure and the input value

Below is the database structure in phpmyadmin

[image]

Below is the front-end input

[image]

in the database there is 3 field 'id , blood_group, blood_avaliable' and the 'blood_group' consist the value according to the input, so i want to be able to update the multiple 'blood_avaliable' field at once according to the input..

please check the image...

Comment: Can you share your HTML that how you are submitting those values ?

Comment: i am actually get the blood_group and blood_avaliable value from the database using the while loop but am unable to know how to updatae all row at once

Comment: @Devintel How are you getting the values from the form?

Answer (score 0):

You should use SQL CASE statement

```
UPDATE `blood_table`
SET `blood_available` = (
  CASE 
    WHEN `blood_type` = 'A+' THEN :blood_available_a_plus
    WHEN `blood_type` = 'A-' THEN :blood_available_a_minus
    ELSE blood_available
  END
)
```